# Cannot get smartctl working

Tags: smartctl, smart

On my debian wheezy server I use a **software raid 1** with two harddisks `dev/sda3` and `dev/sdb3` connected into `dev/md2`:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md2
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
```

The raid seems to be fine, but on one of the disks SMART is not running:

```
smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

sais:

```
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Disabled
```

While `/dev/sdb` gives a lot of SMART information.

I tried to start it with

```
smartctl -s on /dev/sda -T verypermissive not working
```

But it doesn't start:

```
Error SMART Enable failed: scsi error aborted command
Smartctl: SMART Enable Failed.
```

How can I get it running? Or does it mean the disk has a problem?

Comment: Show the output of your array configuration via the RAID-specific utility. Eg for megaraid (most Dell servers) `MegaCli -PDList -aALL`

Comment: Try it with `smartctl -T verypermissive -s on /dev/sda`, the manpage specifies the device to be at the end of the command so perhaps that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: No it doesn't matter if it's at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If S.M.A.R.T. cannot be enabled, not even in rescue mode, this means that the harddisk isn't working correct anymore and **should be replaced**.

Comment: Could you give more details on why do you think this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what kind of RAID controller you're using (the output of `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` could help), but it's likely presenting a virtual drive and hiding the physical ones. Asking an array about its physical health as if it were a single disk doesn't make much sense.

Maybe your RAID solution shows the *actual* disks on different devices? If so, those would be the ones to pass to `smartctl`.

Also check your documentation - maybe there's a separate utility to make the array issue the SMART commands to each disk and report back.

Comment: But it works fine on sdb

Comment: Is sdb related to the array? I may be missing something here.

Comment: I use a **software raid 1** with two harddisks `dev/sda3` and `dev/sdb3` connected into `dev/md2`.